# Jquery - simple gallery with addClass and removeClass

Tags: jquery, css, image, gallery

I have a simple jquery gallery that I am trying to create.

I have it working except, when you click on the thumbs - it does this:

1. replaces the space of an existing thumb with the first image
2. throws off the float with the thumbs going above the main image

   - click on the last thumb to see what I mean

Does anyone know how I can fix this with CSS or Jquery?

I am try to make this super simple.

Thanks

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webdott/zZNBQ/1/

```
    <div>
    <img src="image1.jpg" class="first"/>
    <img src="image2.jpg" />
    </div>

    <style>
    img {float:right;width:10%;margin:1%;}
    .fullview{width:60%;margin:0 4% 0 0;float:left;}
    .first{width:60%;margin:0 4% 0 0;float:left}
    </style>

    <script>
    $('img').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fullview').siblings().removeClass('fullview first');
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the images *before* and *after* the one which is selected are affecting how the larger one displays and is floated. How about floating a large image as a single element, then changing the source of that element to match the clicked element? Like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/zZNBQ/4/).

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function() {
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $('#fullview').attr('src',src);
});
```

and

```
#fullview {
float:left;
max-width:75%;
}

ul {
float:right;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
li img {
    width:50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

or you could do something similar but with [the gallery on the side like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/zZNBQ/3/).

Comment: that's it exactly. Thanks for the help! here is the final that I did: http://jsfiddle.net/webdott/3uzCB/2/

Comment: @simpleme looks nice!

Comment: here is the updated look what I did with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/webdott/5YHyZ/

Comment: @simpleme, I kind of like the idea of the blue price tag, but it obscures part of the image. If I'm buying a house, I'd want to know what the top left of the image has to show!

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a container div and position absolute;

```
<div style="width:40%;float:right;">
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/nvWh2/).

Comment: But then the thumbnails bounce all around!

Comment: thanks SuperScript, that works for the css, JakeParis is the best solution. I really appreciate it.